# MariaDB: Different behaviour if running code from terminal or from an SQL-client due to collation/encoding

Tags: windows, encoding, terminal, mariadb, collation

If I run an sql-code (A)  from HeidiSQL I get error due to collation. I can consider the collation in the sql-code (B) and then it works. But if I run the sql from terminal or from a Perl-script the error happens if I consider collation (B) in the sql-code but works if I remove collation in the code.

Environment: Windows 10, MariaDB 10.4

For example:

```
-- Create minimal table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test0.x0 ;
CREATE TABLE test0.x0 (
  id     INTEGER
, xml_id CHAR(4)
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
;

INSERT INTO test0.x0 VALUES
  (1, '0-03')
, (2, '1-01')
;
```

If I run the following code (A) in HeidiSQL

```
-- Code A
SET @xml_id = '0-03';

SELECT *
FROM test0.x0
WHERE xml_id = @xml_id
;
```

I get this error:

```
/* SQL Fehler (1267): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' */
```

If I run considering collation (code B)

```
-- Code B
SET @xml_id = '0-03';

SELECT *
FROM test0.x0
WHERE xml_id = @xml_id COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
;
```

it runs without error.

But if I submit the code from terminal or from a script considering collation (code B):

```
"c:\Program2\MariaDB 10.4\bin\mysql" -uroot --password=pw -h localhost test0 <i0048.sql
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1253 (42000) at line 8: COLLATION 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'cp850'
```

If I remove the collation setting (code A) it runs without error.

I'm wondering why this happenend and how I can run the code (B) from terminal or from a script avoiding to remove the collation setting (`xml_id = @xml_id COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`) since I use the same code from HeidiSQL or from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Every client have is own charset, maybe look at HeidiSql preference.
You can also try

```
SET @xml_id = '0-03';

SELECT *FROM test0.x0 WHERE xml_id like @xml_id ;
```

Comment: You can show the charset of the connection with :  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';